# Civicrm registration form sending to Paypal but registration info not being sent back to Civicrm

Tags: civievent, paypal, registration, ipn

Using civicrm 4.7.3. We have an event registration form through our civicrm installation on Wordpress 4.4.2. Registrants using this form are sent to PayPal Standard and the payment is received by PayPal but the registrant's information is not being sent back to the Civicrm database. Absolutely no information is sent back from PayPal. This worked using the PayPal sandbox **but not** the live site. My payment processor is set to PayPal with the correct merchant account email and the url set to https://www.paypal.com (Test payments now set to same since site is live). IPN is enabled in PayPal. My civicrm_system_log table shows the sandbox notices but nothing since I took the site live.

Help! Does anyone have an idea why this would be the case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They are working on it.  I have the same issue.  Waiting patiently for the fix: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18107?filter=-4&jql=text%20~%20%22paypal%22%20ORDER%20BY%20createdDate%20DESC

Comment: After reading the ticket it seems a different issue perhaps. I only have the one Paypal Standard payment processor and the registrations don't show up as pending. They don't show up at all. The paypal payments get logged within the paypal site but I never receive the registration info back on our site. The IPN appears to be sent from paypal but never shows up in civicrm.

Comment: The setting of the registration as Pending is a CiviCRM function once someone registers or signs up.  The fact that the contribution in your system is not set to pending seems really strange.  What is the status of the contribution in CiviCRM?  What is the status of the registration?

Comment: The contribution does not show up in CivicCRM whatsoever. The only way I know a registration occurred is when PayPal sends me a notification.

Comment: Just to reiterate, the PayPal sandbox sent the reg info back to CiviCrm. The PayPal live site does not.